# Toolbar inside fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer, toolbar

In my project I have one activity and different fragments, and for some raisons I used the toolbar inside the fragments.

I have also a drawer menu, and that's what I added in my main activity

```
mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, this.mDrawerLayout, 0, 0)
    {

        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawer) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawer);
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawer) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawer);
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
    };
    mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
.
.
.
public void setDrawerState(boolean isEnabled) {
    if (isEnabled) {
        mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();

    } else {
        mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }
}
```

I have two fragments: home and detail fragment
in my homeFragment, I expect to see the hamburger icon, when I click it the drawer menu get started( that's what happen when I click it the first time).

code in HomeFragment:

```
((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    ((MainActivity) mContext).setDrawerState(true);
```

next when I start the detail fragment from the home fragment I have to see the up caret icon, and when I click it, I have go back to home fragment.

code in DetailFragment:

```
((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    ((MainActivity) mContext).setDrawerState(false);
```

when I go back the hamburger icon is not working any more, and sometime the back icon not working too for other low level fragmants.

is what I did correct or there is another better way to do it

any help please.

Comment: It should be enough to do `setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)` and `setHomeButtonEnabled(true)` only once, in your `onCreate(Bundle)` method, after calling `setContentView(int)`

Comment: each fragment has its own toolbar

Comment: That might be it. If you're using multiple Toolbars with a single drawer, it might get it out of sync (just speculating). Can you try to call `syncState()` after you call `setDrawerState(boolean)`?

Comment: I already added `syncState()` inside `setDrawerState` , check the code above